# How to anchor a website to a usb flash drive?

Tags: html, css

So I've developed a website with multiple (10) pages, including a home page, and each page has links to the others. But when demo'ing the site, the links point to "C://users/hp/(etc etc)". Is there a way to simply point the links on the website to their parent folder, wherever that folder is located? I want to be able to put it on a flash drive, give that flash drive to a friend, and for them to be able to plug it in and use the website without changing or moving anything.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood you, but I guess you are looking for http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/

Comment: you can use php variables to store path for you, and then they will automatically change paths with server variables. Else use HTML `base` tag to clear confusing tree

Comment: See, the individual pages have links to the other pages. Right now, the links read "C://users/hp/desktop/website/Brussels/brussels.html" (and so on) but how exactly can I rewrite those to simply point to the other pages, which are all located in their own folders within one parent folder (in the case of my example, a folder named "website")?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't host the page, or put the project up to github?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use *relative paths* instead of *absolute* ones:

- `C:\Users\hp\foo\bar.txt` This is called *absolute path*.
- `..\..\foo\bar.txt` This is called *relative path* (Any path that doesn't begin with the root of the filesystem, in your case, it is `C:`).

In relative paths, `..` mean the parent directory, and `.` means the current directory. So to refer to the parent directory use `../` then complete the path from this directory to the file.

Comment: Thank you. I did read an article about this, but for some reason, you summed it up much better than they. Again, thanks a ton.